# Why doesn't ItemsSource bind to my custom CollectionChanged event

Tags: c#, .net, windows-8

This is the weirdest thing I've ever faced. As in Windows 8 MS removed filtering and sorting from CollectionViewSource, I've had to build my own, called `CollectionView<T>`. `CollectionView` has a View property of type `IObservableCollection<T>`, a custom interface I made just to keep things abstracted. Its definition is pretty simple

```
public interface IObservableCollection<T> : IReadOnlyList<T>, INotifyCollectionChanged
{
}
```

Then, I have my internal class which implements this interface:

```
internal class FilteredSortedCollection<T> : IObservableCollection<T>
{
    public event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;

    public void RaiseCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        var copy = CollectionChanged;
        if (copy != null)
            copy(this, args);
    }

    public Func<IEnumerator<T>> RequestEnumerator { get; set; }
    public Func<int> RequestCount { get; set; }
    public Func<int, T> RequestItem { get; set; }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return RequestEnumerator();
    }

    public int Count { get { return RequestCount(); } }
    public T this[int index] { get { return RequestItem(index); } }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Things worked until here. CollectionView filters and orders properly, and the View works as expected. Except when I bind it to a ListView.ItemsSource property **it just behaves as if it didn't implemented `INotifyCollectionChanged`**. Nobody listens to the CollectionChanged event (checked with the debugger) and **the UI doesn't update with new elements added**. But if I add some items and then set the ItemsSource property, the UI updates. Just as if it were a normal, non-observable list.

Does anybody know what can be happening here? I've tried deleting the `IObservableCollection` interface, so `FilteredSortedCollection` just implemented `IReadOnlyList<T>` and `INotifyCollectionChanged` directly, but it didn't worked.

Comment: 1) does it work with other ItemControls (ListBox) ?

Comment: 2) what happens when you replace IReadOnlyList<T> with IList<T> ?

Comment: It doesn't work with other ItemControls, and using IList<T> does not help either. I also tried with IEnumerable<T> instead of IReadOnlyList<T> and nothing.

Answer (score 2):

Your collection needs to implement IList. I just ran into the same issue where I had implemented IList which worked great in my Windows Phone app, but when I attempted to use the view model for Windows 8 application it wasn't honoring the changed events.

I added the implementation of IList to my class and now everything works as expected